# Initial values for CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: django, forms

I'm initializing a form using:

```
MultiSubscriptionForm(initial={'email': user.email})
```

In my form I'd also like to initialize a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget to check a set of checkboxes. How can I do that?

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More or less the same actually, just pass a list of values and it works.

```
MultiSubscriptionForm(initial={
    'email': user.email,
    'multiple_field': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
})
```

Comment: Ever have one of those problems where you try something 50 different ways, then wake up the next morning and the second thing you try works even though you're pretty sure it's one of the things you did the night before?  This was one of those for me, and your answer did the trick (even though I'm could've sworn I'd already tried this....) Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem, Where I am the multiple checkboxes need to select dynamically (default selection of checkboxes) with initial value. I can able to manage the by passing the list.

`mylist=['None','Fixed','Error']`

`error= forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = formfields.ErrorType,widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple(),initial = mylist)`

If I write the above code in my form class the values in mylist were selected by default when the form loads. your answer "Passing the values as list" solved my actual problem

Thanks for the clue :-)

-Vikram

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia)